# rvest returning character(0)

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'd like to scrape the abstract from this journal: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.biopsych.2020.05.020

Using "view source", it seems that the abstract is under "div.section-paragraph".

Using rvest:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://doi.org/10.1016/j.biopsych.2020.05.020'
abstract <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("div.section-paragraph") %>% html_text()
```

This code returns character(0) or character(empty)

I've also tried using the selector gadget, and since it only lets me select one paragraph at a time, I tried to scrape the first paragraph of the abstract ('Background').

Replacing "div.section-paragraph" with xpath from selector gadget:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://doi.org/10.1016/j.biopsych.2020.05.020'
abstract <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "section-paragraph", " " ))]') %>% html_text()
```

This also returns character(0).

How do I scrape the abstract for this?

Comment: `abstract` doesn't return `character(0)` for me. In fact it has all the relevant text that you are looking for.

Comment: do you know what might be causing the discrepancy?

Comment: Suggest saving the html file locally and then trying your code again,  I had the same problem but this fixed it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

Comment: try with the re-direct url: https://www.biologicalpsychiatryjournal.com/article/S0006-3223(20)31626-7/fulltext

Comment: That works! Do you perhaps know why I have to use the re-direct url? And do you know how I might be able to override this?